# Showing conditional expectation equivalence

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

**Question:** I have a random one-hot vector $B\in\{0,1\}^L$, where the position of the one entry follows $\text{Categorical}(\pi)$ where $\pi\in\mathbb{R}^L$. Given a constant (non-random) $L\times L$ matrix $M$ and a Gaussian vector $G\sim N(0_L,M)$, is it true that
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[
\mathbb{E}[B|MB+G]B^\top 1_L
\Big]
=\mathbb{E}[B],
$$
where $1_L$ is a vector with $L$ ones and $0_L$ is a vector of $L$ zeros.

**My attempt:** Expanding out the expectation, I get
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[B|MB+G](B_1+\dots+B_L)\Big],
$$
and since we know from the property of the one-hot vector that entries must sum to one, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[B|MB+G](B_1+\dots+B_L)\Big]
=\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[B|MB+G]\Big]
=\mathbb{E}[B].
$$
Is this correct?